# Linux cant install package of apt-get or aptitude install correct

Tags: linux, installation, package, apt-get, aptitude

I would like to install some files on linux.
On my linux pc 64 bit i can install the file normally.
Later on a 32 bit linux workstation that didnt work. I get the faults

on install i get the faults like this....

```
Err: http:/de.archive.ubunti.com/ubunti raring /main freetds-common all 0.91-3 404 NOT FOUND
Err: http:/de.archive.ubunti.com/ubunti raring / libct4 i386 0.91-3 404 NOT FOUND
Failed to fetch de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/freetds/freetds-common 0.91-3 all.deb 404 NOT FOUND
```

after install the freetds has not the i value next to the package of aptitude search but also the p value next to the i.

What can i make to install packages there correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have internet connection then try to update your repository files:

apt-get update

https://askubuntu.com/questions/222348/what-does-sudo-apt-get-update-do

Comment: Thanks but update also dont work. i have an internet connection, but with update i get following faults: W:failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dist ... 404 Not Found [IP: the Ipadress] AND E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead

Comment: check your sources file at /etc/apt/sources.list and update it with the new repositories list

Comment: hope it help http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ or search google for ubuntu sources.list updated

Answer (score 0):

The error output is pretty much trivial `404 NOT FOUND`, you are trying to access smth with doesn't exist

Go over following step

1. Check if you have correct network setup i.e.
   `ping de.archive.ubuntu.com` if its not working try with direct ip lookup
2. Update the repository metadata `freetds-common_0.91-3_all.deb` you are trying to access is not there but the newer version `freetds-common_0.91-5_all.deb` is, so you will need to refresh the repository metadata.

Comment: apt-get update doesnt work. it ignores sone files and failed to fetch others with 404 not found

Comment: under http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ i dont find the folder raring-updates, raring-backreports and so on. think thatś the problem. what it means?

Comment: Can you please copy/paste here the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list `

Comment: that's on another workstation but i think itś because of the raring directory also in sources.list. Can i maybe take another source for this?